# "At all" vs "Not at all" in negated sentences

Tags: word-usage, negative-polarity-items

If I say *That makes sense to me.* I would say definitively *at all*.

> That makes sense to me at all.

But in the negated sentence I'm not sure. I've the feeling, that it is still *at all*. But if I say *not at all* it still sounds OK to my ears but I would, though, separate it with a comma or even with a full stop.

Which one is correct?

> That makes no sense to me at all.

or

> That makes no sense to me, not at all.
>
> That makes no sense to me, by no means at all.

Comment: Your original construct `That makes sense to me at all.` is actually awkward to me.  While your first formulation of the negation is the expected one.

Comment: @JoshuaDrake Oh, why? Why is the *positive* sentence so odd? Would you say something like *That makes absolutely sense to me?* instead?

Comment: _That absolutely makes sense to me_. or _That makes absolute sense to me_.  If we really want to keep all in there, _That all makes sense to me_.  Or a few other variations.  Keep in mind that I'm a native speaker with a California bent, so I am not representative of British or necessarily even American usage.

Comment: @Joshua Drake: Could be your Californian "Valley speak" showing there - I think that usage of *absolutely* probably corresponds to *really, truly*, rather than the literal *all, completely*.

Comment: Others have noted the flaw in the first example. I'd say the right way to say it would be something like, "That makes excellent sense to me" or "That makes very good sense to me".

Answer (score 15, accepted):

*At all* is a **Negative Polarity Item** [(***NPI***)](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf). That means it is one of a long list of English words, phrases, idioms, and constructions that can only occur grammatically in a Negative environment.

Rather than being *"awkward"* or *"ugly"* (which are esthetic judgements and not grammar),

- **That makes sense to me at all.*

is simply ungrammatical, since there is no negation present to license the use of *at all*.
So it's incongruous here; what could it possibly add to the meaning in such an environment?

In a grammatical sentence, say,

- *That doesn't make sense to me **at all**.*
- *That makes no sense to me **at all**.*
- *Nobody understands that **at all**.*

*at all* functions as an intensifier of the negation, meaning something like 'in even the most insignificant manner'. But without a negative environment to license it, *at all* makes no sense at all.

There's a lot more to say about [Negation and Negative Polarity](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/CELS-Negation.pdf), but this is a very simple case.

**Edit:** Specifically, just to get it all on the record, 
for the future, here's the list of Negative Triggers from
 http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf. 
(*If*-Clauses fall under "III. Hypothetical Clauses)

**Negative ‘Triggers’**

Notes:

- NPIs are illustrated here by the prototype English Negative Polarity Item ***any***.
- *A asterisk before an sentence means (that) the sentence is **ungrammatical**.
- Parentheses indicate optional material (that) one can either omit or include.
- The first few sentences give grammatical negatives versus ungrammatical affirmatives. After that you're expected to find your own ungrammatical affirmatives. (It's rather [fun](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/Subversive.pdf), actually; they really sound terrible)
- **I.** Overt negatives:

  - **A.** **not** [w/ NPI clausemate or complement]
  - **He (did know/knew) anybody.*
  - *He didn't know anybody.*
  - **He (did claim/claimed) (that) he knew anybody*.
  - *He didn’t claim (that) he knew anybody*.
  - **He thought (that) he knew anybody.*
  - *He didn’t think (that) he knew anybody.*
  - **B.** Incorporated negatives
  - *I **doubt** (that) he knows anybody.*
  - *It’s **unlikely** (that) he knows anybody.*
  - *It’s **improbable** (that) he knows anybody.*
  - *He **dislikes** anybody(’s) reminding him.*
  - *He **prevented** her (from) seeing anyone.*
  - *I **kept** her **from** telling anybody.*
  - **C.** Negative frequency adverbs
  - *I **seldom/rarely** see any of them.*
  - *He **hardly/scarcely** knows anyone.*
  - **D.** Quantifiers & quantified adverbs
  - ***Only** Bill did any of the homework.*
  - ***Few** people see any use for it.*
  - **A few people see any use for it.* (*few* is negative; ***a*** few isn't)
- **II.** Questions (overt and embedded)

  - *Did you see anybody?*
  - *How does anybody stand this?*
  - *I wonder how anybody stands this.*
- **III.** Hypothetical clauses.

  - *Tell me **if** you see anyone.*
  - *He asked **whether** I saw anyone.*
  - *Tell me **whatever** anybody says.*
  - *Check the list again, **lest** we forget anyone.*
  - *I’ll read it aloud, **unless** anyone objects.*
- **IV.** Comparatives, superlatives, etc.

  - *There’s **more/less** here than anybody knew.*
  - *He **prefers** beer to any other drink.*
  - *He’d **rather** die than hurt anyone.*
  - *He’s **as** good **as** anyone expected.*
  - *He’s the **fastest** one (that) anybody knows of.*
  - *I saw him **before** anybody (did).*
  - *I’m **surprised** (that) he knows anybody.*
  - *It’s **too** dark to recognize anything.*
  - *He left **without** anybody noticing (it).*
  - *That’s **hard/tough** for anybody to do.*

Comment: I take it a "Negative environment" includes "unlikely, but possible" contexts, such as *"He will be late, if he comes at all"*.

Comment: There's a (not totally complete) list of Negative "Triggers" (i.e, environments that license NPIs) along with the (not totally complete) list of NPIs in the first link above, repeated [here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/NPIs.pdf).

Comment: I'll edit the answer to give the examples from there. Thanks.

Comment: OK, done. Remember, you asked :-)

Comment: haha - after my first comment it did actually occur to me that I could have suggested *"I'll be surprised if he comes at all"*. Which at the time I couldn't relate to the concept of "negativity". But I followed your second link, saw it at the end of the list, and suddenly got a feel for how all those different usages interconnect.

Comment: Finally, I got the time to work through all links. Thank you for the detailed answer. That's a lot more than being asked but all the information was really helpful to me. Hence, I choose this response as *the answer*.

Comment: **"'*That makes sense to me at all.*' is simply ungrammatical, since there is no negation present to license the use of at all."** Could you clarify this? Suppose *"That makes sense to me at all (vertices).* Now the "all" infers the word vertices in the context. Now I think the sentence would make sense, agree? I am learning [this puzzle](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111352/at-all-the-vertices-what-does-this-mean?lq=1).

Answer (score 5):

OP has usage of *"at all"* the wrong way round - we only normally use this in the negative.

The only really sound example sentence is **That makes no sense to me at all**, but I think even that would probably normally be phrased  **That makes no sense at all to me**.

> ***That makes sense to me at all** is definitely unsound (but *That all makes sense to me* is okay).
>
> ***?That makes no sense to me, not at all***. Some may find this acceptable, but I could only endorse either *That makes no sense to me, **none** at all*, or perhaps *That **does not** make sense to me, not at all*.
>
> ***That makes no sense to me, by no means at all** is also unsound. Primarily because of the tautology of *by no means* and *[not] at all*, but the double negation *no sense/no means* is also ugly.

Answer (score 1):

The only way the sentence "That makes sense to me at all" makes sense to a native English speaker is if spoken sarcastically, with heavy emphasis on either "that" or "me", such that the actual meaning is "that does not make sense to me".

Your other three constructions are all valid, in somewhat different ways.  "That makes no sense to me at all" is the standard form.  The other two are something in the line of rhetorical flourishes for extra emphasis.

Comment: ...unless an inferred meaning for the word `"all"` like: *"That makes sense to me at all (vertices)"* where speaker may leave out the word verrtices if audience knows the topic at hand. In this case, it is not sarcastic but precise meaning. So the sentence depends on the context. Anyway good point +1 for sarcasm, possible.

Answer (score 0):

I have to agree that the original sentence "That makes sense to me at all." is incorrect. In that usage it needs a negative, to make it grammatically correct. However FumbleFingers statement "I take it a "Negative environment" includes "unlikely, but possible" contexts, such as "He will be late, if he comes at all"." got me thinking. What if I played with that example and Said instead: 'He is an emergency room doctor. He reports to work at all hours of the day'. There is no negative environment in that statement, but I do believe it works.

Comment: The "at all" in "at all hours of the day" is completely different to the "at all" in my question, isn't it?