# Can I use "anymore" with "nothing"?

Tags: negation, agreement

Normally, *anymore* (or *any more* in UK) meaning *any longer* used as an adverb not a as determiner, can be found in negative, conditional, or interrogative sentences. 
Americans may use *anymore* in positive sentences, but I'd like to skip this subject if possible :)

**My question** : is the use of *nothing* makes the sentence negative despite it's grammatically a positive sentence and so allows the use of *anymore* ?

Can I say and write :

> Shara has always hated this town but she stayed there for her mother. Her mother has just died. From now on, nothing prevents her from moving on anymore

And what about *nothing else ... anymore* or *almost nothing ... anymore* ? They still both express the negation but not the COMPLETENESS. Is it a trouble?

> John has a very weak will. And Sofia thinks if he tries cocaine just one time, then for him, nothing else will matter anymore

Another **less important question** : I find *From now on* and *anymore* a bit redundant. Is it the case or it's OK?

Thank you for all your remarks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Anymore* (*Any more*) is a [***Negative Polarity Item***](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299) (NPI),  and *nothing* is a negative trigger word.

NPIs require a negative trigger word in their context, usually in a special syntactic construction.
It doesn't matter whether the clause is "positive", taken together, or not. It's the trigger that matters.

An NPI that occurs outside the scope of a negative trigger, however, is quite ungrammatical.
(though American English does have a "positive anymore" dialect, where *anymore* = *nowadays*).

- *I doubt he goes there anymore*, but not **I believe he goes there anymore.*
- *Few people go there anymore*, but not **A few people go there anymore.*
- *Only Bill goes there anymore*, but not **Even Bill goes there anymore.*

(except, again, in positive *anymore* dialects, where people can say things like

- *That's where I take my dry cleaning anymore.*
  -- meaning "That's where I take it **now**; I used to take it elsewhere")

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing ungrammatical. But it is clumsy and redundant to say "From now on.... anymore."  No additional nuance of meaning is provided.

I would say:

Her mother has just died. Now nothing prevents her from moving on.

The "Now nothing.." provides the total completeness of the situation and in a manner befitting the parsimony of death.