# Emphasis of this double negative?

Tags: double-negation, negative-polarity-items

> Without which, we would be able to act at all.

I’m hearing this in my own head as, “Without which, we would **not** be able to act at all.”

So I'm wondering, is the former just a cleaner and less hectoring version of the second, with both meaning the same thing?

Comment: No, it's not "a cleaner and less hectoring version". It's gibberish, not valid English in the first place. You probably need to read up on [negative polarity items](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polarity_item)

Comment: Looks like somebody just a word out.

Comment: Ask yourself, if it is correct, what is the adverbial phrase 'at all' qualifying?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be about a mistake. If there is good reason to believe that the sentence is correct, please edit the question to support that assertion.

Comment: ‘a sense of futurity, without which we would be able to act at all.’

Comment: ‘a sense of futurity, without which we would be able to act at all.’  That is the quote from a Terry Eagleton book, quoted in a review.  Is it possible that the first part that is left out would make this grammatical?

Comment: Clearly a toyp.

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇: The passage seems to be drawn from [this](http://marxandphilosophy.org.uk/reviewofbooks/reviews/2014/991) review, misquoting [this](http://books.google.com/books?id=B1bncW0houYC&pg=PA61&lpg=PA61&dq=%22a+sense+of+futurity+without+which%22&source=bl&ots=j-MmPB1Bl0&sig=YR0heOfs79BqAOsKES_lh-b6cuk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=bPGqU-fkLpafyASehIC4BA&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAg#v=onepage&q=%22a%20sense%20of%20futurity%20without%20which%22&f=false) passage, which reads ***unable** to act at all.* So I concur in closing, but congratulate OP on a sharp eye.

Comment: @StoneyB Holy Detective Work, Batman!

Comment: @Mr.ShinyandNew安宇 Well, when OP brought Terry Eagleton's name into it I had to defend the honour of the LitCrit profession.

Answer (score 2):

The reason you're hearing the written sentence in your mind's ear with a *not* in it
is that
that way, the sentence is grammatical.

[*At all* is a Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299), which means that it can't appear grammatically at all,
unless it's inside the scope of a negative trigger; and by far the simplest and most common
negative trigger (linguists would say the "default" or "unmarked" trigger) in English is ***not***.

*Without*, which **is** a negative trigger, appears at the beginning of the sentence and doesn't command (and therefore can't trigger) *at all*, which is in a subordinate clause.

Thus, your brain obligingly supplied *not* for your mind's ear, because your brain knows English syntax, whether you do or not.

Comment: Footnote: By the way, that funny feeling you get when you read _Without which, we would be able to act at all_ is precisely the feeling of making a negative grammaticality judgement and awarding a star. In case you were wondering what I mean by "grammatical", this is ***IT***.

Comment: The footnote is even better than the body! - but OP may not understand that *awarding a star* means *marking with an asterisk to signal ungrammaticality*.

Comment: I would've done it in the footnote, but the typography of putting a star at the front of an italicized sentence in comments is a little flaky; sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't, and if it doesn't, I hafta fix it in 5 minutes or start over. It's not so bad in answers proper, just comments. Dunno why.

Comment: @JohnLawler I sometimes skirt the issue by using U+2217       ASTERISK OPERATOR, the ∗ character.