# What is the grammatical explanation of the phrase "all that" as in the sentence "I didn't understand all that much"

Tags: grammar

What is the grammatical explanation of the phrase “all that” as in the sentence “I didn’t understand all that much”?

> 1. I didn’t understand all that much.

I came across the sentence above, and now wonder if someone could explain the grammar about the phrase “all that”.

For example:

> 2. All that glitters is not gold.

In this case, ‘all’ seems a pronoun; ‘that’, a relative pronoun. But ‘that’ in the sentence (1) does not introduce a relative clause. Therefore, the usage may be different.

I do not have any other clues to find out the grammatical explanation.

---

After discussing with John, I think it is a good idea to add another sentence for further understanding.

> 3. I didn't understand all that.

This sentence is very similar to (1), but it could be structurally different from (1).

I hope this comparison help us understand these usage more precisely.

Answer (score 3):

*(All) that much* is a quantifier, but more importantly it's an idiomatic [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299).

That is, it can only occur felicitously within the scope of a negative trigger.
Like *didn’t*. Notice that you can certainly say

- *I **didn't** understand all that much of what she said.*

but you can't say

- **I understood all that much of what she said.*

because there is no negative trigger present.

In the appropriate negative context, it means, basically, not much at all

- *I doubt he enjoyed all that much of the play.*
- *It isn't as if she weighed all that much.*

And it can also be used with other quantifiers and qualifiers besides *much*:

- *She isn't all that gorgeous.*
- *If it's all that important, why don't we hear more about it?*

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Seeing variations of this expression, I found the sentence "I did not understand all that." Therefore, I though 'much' in the original sentence can be separable from 'all that'. What do you think?

Comment: Different construction, different meaning and grammar. _That much_ or _all that much_ (the _all_ is meaningless and serves as an optional intensifier) is a frozen unit **when it is used as a negative polarity item**. That's what we're talking about. _All that_ is a variant of _all of that_, which is not a negative polarity item and has a meaningful quantifier _all_. You can say it in an affirmative statement: _I understood all that._ But you can't use _all that much_ that way: *_I understood all that much_.

Answer (score 2):

1. *All* is an adjective; to be more precise, a determiner. *That* is a demonstrative pronoun that functions as a noun; it is modified by *all*. The construction is similar to *all that stuff*, except that *that* functions as an adjective in that sentence, modifying *stuff*. Here we don't have *stuff*, so *that* takes the place of a noun.
2. *All* is an adjective/determiner that functions as a noun; many adjectives can function like nouns, such as in *the weak perished* and *red is nice*. *That* is a relative pronoun referring back to *all*, its antecedent. It introduces the relative clause *that glitters*. The main clause is *all [that glitters] is not gold*: the relative clause is *restricting/defining*, because it restricts what *all* refers to. Without it, *all* would refer to more things than with the restrictive relative clause.

Comment: Thank you for the clear answer. I can understand your opinion clearly, but I have a problem. Do you modify pronoun with an adjective/determiner?

Comment: @243: Yes: the the pronoun stands for and functions like a noun, it can be modified by an adjective/determiner.

Comment: @ Cerberus: I see. You are right. For example, you could say large one, the one, the first one etc. The pronoun 'one' can be modified by those modifier. But, it seems awkward to say 'large that', the that, or the first that. Could 'all that' be a special case?

Comment: @243: Absolutely, *that* is a very special case, because it is a pronoun. Not all nouns can take all adjectives, and *that* only functions as one: it is unlike more "normal" nouns. An unusual noun like *the rich* also cannot take most adjectives: **the large rich* is not really possible. And the noun *red* in *red is a colour* cannot take an article: **the red is a colour* is wrong, because *the red* means something else.

Answer (score 0):

Syntactically: "all that" in "all that much" is an adverbial phrase.

Semantical history: if you share knowledge about something or somebody with you interlocutor, if suffices to drop a key word or two and then say "and all that." Example: a well-known maths text called *Div, Curl, Grad, and All That*. Or talking about Elon Musk, he's wealthy and a genius... and all that. We both know the list. "All That" then became an idiom for all things desirable. Example: a movie called *She's All That*. But sometimes we find that these glowing reputations were perhaps a bit exaggerated. Meh, not all that. Not as great as everybody seems to think. And now "not all that" simply means "not particularly" "not to any great extent."

In "all that glitters" the "all that" is **not** this adverbial phrase. The two words each do their own normal thing, as in "everything which."