# Double negative complicated with the use of 'hard'

Tags: meaning, double-negation

What does the author mean by this: 'It is hard not to conclude there is none...'
Here is the whole context:

> What is the cure? It is hard not to conclude there is none: some problems have no solution, one can only manage things as best one can.

Is this a case of triple negative because of the use of the word 'hard'?
Can you explain what is really being said there?

Comment: You're perhaps thinking of _hardly_ rather than _hard_.

Comment: "Hard" is a negative trigger.  See https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63718/at-all-vs-not-at-all-in-negated-sentences/63728#63728 by John Lawler and the link to a list of negative polarity and negative trigger items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is **the desire, or preference, of the author**.  The author **wants** there to be a cure.  He wants to be able to conclude that there is a cure, and so **he does not want to conclude that there is no cure**.

Unfortunately, after looking at the evidence, he finds that he is unable to do this:  therefore, **it is hard not to conclude that there is no cure**.  It's like saying *"I am reluctantly forced to conclude that there is no cure"*, or, perhaps, *"It looks like there is no cure.  I have not formally made that decision yet, but it's hard to see how I can make any other decision"*

Note that "Hard not to" isn't the same thing as "easy to" - the key difference is in what you might **want** to do.

Consider "It's easy to kill yourself with a gun" versus "It's hard not to kill yourself with a gun".  The first is true - point it at your head and pull the trigger.  The second is not true, because you can just put the gun down and walk away.

Answer (score 1):

No, because the word "hard" is not a negative.  In this context, "hard not to" implies that it is "easy to" but "hard" is still not a negative.

Comment: I suppose ''not hard to'' means "easy to", "hard not to" means more like "tempting".

Comment: If "hard not to" equals "easy to", as you suggest, that is already a double negative, isn't it? Add the word "none" and you have a triple negative.

Answer (score 0):

The meaning is far stronger than "easy to" or "tempted". It means the obvious conclusion is that there is no cure **and** nothing exists suggesting any alternative conclusion.