# Meaning of Anyone

Tags: quantifiers, some-any

Could anyone help me?

If I say : Will you stay with me if I speak to anyone?

Anyone means : whatever who (sorry I can say otherwise) I mean "anyone" like : Anyone can work here, it will go!
Thanks :-)

Comment: "Will you stay with me if I speak to someone?" means virtually the same as "Will you stay with me while I speak to someone? [I may not if you don't]" // But "Will you stay with me if I speak to anyone?" can only be used in the sense [A]: "Will you stay with me if I speak to _anyone_?" ... [B] "Anyone except Catwoman."

Comment: And Houw could I say : I am not anyone : without it means : I am no one.

Comment: "Anyone" does not really have a meaning, so stop worrying about it. It's just a chunk of grammar, in this case Negative Polarity. It turns out that _if_-clauses are negative triggers because they refer to possibility (like questions). That means that NPIs like _any, ever, budge, in weeks,_ etc. can occur there. Take away the negative environment and it's nonsense: *_He got mad at me because I talked to anyone_. This is just one example; there are [a **LOT** of negative polarity items](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is but if you're asking for clarification regarding your statement, then I can say that "Will you stay with me if I speak to anyone?" is similar to asking, "If I talk to some person, will you stay with me?"

---

See the definitions by the Merriam-Webster dictionary and the Collins English dictionary, respectively, below:

#### Merriam-Webster definition

> **anyone**: any person at all

#### Collins English Dictionary defintion

> **anyone**: You use anyone or anybody in statements with negative meaning to indicate in a general way that nobody is present or involved in an action.

---

You can see more example sentences of the use of "anyone" [here](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/anyone) and [here](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/anyone).