# Hardly/Scarcely...than

Tags: grammaticality

I have been taught that "Hardly...than" doesn't exist. However, I have found many sources like Longman and Merriam-Webster stating otherwise, so I've become very confused.

It is true that "hardly" can come with "than" as in:

- *Hardly had he come home than it started to rain*

carrying the same meaning as

- *Hardly had he come when/before it started to rain*?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the ELL. It would help if you stated your question as a question. I see no interrogation mark. See [tour](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Also, please note that "than" is for comparisons and "then" is for sequences in time. You seem to have them mixed up in your second sentence

Comment: Dear Juliana Karasawa Souza,

I see your point, but it is true that I did not mix them up because I have seen them in aforementioned dictionaries as observed here:

[link](https://www.ldoceonline.com/ko/dictionary/no-sooner-hardly-had-than)
[link](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hardly%2Fscarcely%20than)

Sincere,
OP

Comment: Please give links and actual quotes for the information you say you've found in Longman and M-W. I can't find it.

Comment: To my surprise, I find _than_ acceptable (though not as good as _when_) in _Hardly had he come home than it started to rain_. I have no idea why; it's terrible without the negative preposing: *_He had hardly come home than it started to rain_, which makes me suspect this is a negative phenomenon;baseline comparison clauses beginning with _than_ in comparatives are negative environments.

Answer (score 2):

[AHD](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=hardly) says about the use of the adverb ***hardly***:

> *Hardly* and other minimizing adverbs are properly followed by ***when*** and not ***than*** in sentences like
>
> - I had ***hardly*** walked inside [***when***/than] it began to rain.
>
> In our 2008 survey, *79 percent of the Usage Panel rejected the use of **than*** in the previous sentence.

So the use with *than* is still controversial and the main argument against it is that it normally follows comparatives (like *sooner* in ***no sooner... than***). However others have argued that in ***hardly... than***, *than* is used to show contrast between two situations.

Answer (score 1):

To my surprise, I find *than* acceptable (though not as good as *when*) in

- *Hardly had he come home than it started to rain*.

It's terrible without the negative preposing, though:

- **He had hardly come home than it started to rain*

which makes me suspect this is a phenomenon of negation.

After all, aside from the fact that *hardly, barely, scarcely,* and *rarely* are all negative triggers themselves, baseline comparison clauses in comparatives (the clauses that begin with *than*) are also negative environments, as the [NPI](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299) *ever* below shows.

- *He got wetter than he **ever** expected on the walk home.*

---

**EDIT**

In retrospect, I think

- *Hardly had he come home than it started to rain*.

is acceptable because *hardly* is a mimic of the common idiom *no sooner*

- *No sooner had he come home than it started to rain.*

which is both negative **and** comparative, therefore licensing *than*. *Hardly* is somewhat negative, as noted, but not comparative; *no sooner* is both.

To the extent that *hardly had he* sounds like *no sooner had he*, it works.
Of course, mimicry is very much a YMMV phenomenon.

Comment: But no mimicry of _He had no sooner come home than it started to rain._