# position of 'ever' with a perfect gerund

Tags: adverbs, word-order, gerunds

The adverb 'ever' usually comes in mid-position, that is before the verb, after the auxiliary – if there is one – and after the first auxiliary if there are more than one. (Practical English Usage, fully revised fourth edition, Oxford University Press, first published in 2016, pages 199-200)

> Have you **ever** criticised anyone?

> Have you **ever** been criticised by anyone?

Why then does it not keep the same position in the perfect gerund?

> He denied **ever** having criticised anyone.

> He denied **ever** having been criticised by anyone.

Comment: Both "He denied ever having criticised anyone" and "He denied having ever criticised anyone" sound OK to me (but feel free to check in a corpus). Is there a reason you think one of them is wrong, and if so which one?

Comment: Here's another _Why?_ question about a syntactic rule. The answer is always "Nobody knows".

Comment: @JohnLawler I like the "Dad" answer: "Because".

Answer (score 2):

This has nothing to do with gerunds, but rather with the constructions *ever* is in.

The most important thing to note about *ever* is that it's a [Negative Polarity Item](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/63728/15299) (like *anyone*). NPIs have their own grammar rules; try the last two example sentences with *reported* instead of *denied* to see:

- **He reported ever having criticised anyone*
- **He reported ever having been criticised by anyone*

That's because *deny* is a negative trigger and *report* isn't. The first two examples are questions, which are also negative triggers. Notice, however, that a direct answer to either one is ungrammatical:

- **Yes, I have ever criticised anyone*
- **Yes, I have ever been criticised by anyone*

because statements are not negative triggers.

As for position, the questions are simple sentences, with *ever* occurring according to the rule. But the second examples are complex sentences, and the *ever* is in the subordinate clause, where it doesn't follow the same placement rules.

Comment: I think there's an *asserted/reported* slip in the text here.

Answer (score -1):

Gerunds and infinitives are **non-finite verb forms**.

With them, the **adverbs** which usually come in mid-postion have to come **before the auxiliary or auxiliaries if there are any**.

Comment: That is what I meant by 'why': is there some kind of rule which can justify a  change of position in the case of gerunds. The same would apply to an adverb used with an infinitive: to never have done something (American English) never to have done something (British English), with the adverb coming before the auxiliary in both cases. 'Because' answers are useless.